# Sort SQL string column with currency

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL database that has a column that is a string. The data inside is numbers such as..

```
$12,000,394.09
$56,874.94
$110,339,384.11
```

It is a string column but I am wanting to sort it with lowest on top. Is it possible to do this? Right now I have only tried the simple..

```
SELECT * FROM sales ORDER BY saleamount DESC
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

@Brian - Error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended      
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:762)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1309)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:422)
    at TestServ.processRequest(TestServ.java:37)
    at TestServ.doGet(TestServ.java:116)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What Db engine do you use?

Comment: Why not change the column type to a number and don't store the currency or store it in a different column

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer. And I am using Java for retrieving the content.

Comment: Do you have commas as well?

Comment: Yes, just like in the code above.

Comment: To sort the strings as number you would need to convert them to numbers when sorting. That is possible, but quite inefficient. Is there a good reason why they are not stored as numbers?

Comment: To add to what Guffa wrote, you can probably use To_Number function of Oracle to convert the strings to numbers.

Comment: I kept it varchar because I wasn't sure what users would enter for currency prefix. This is all a learning curve for me into databases and Java code at the moment. I will advance on my code after my first revision is completed. I am looking into Brian Demilia response at the moment.

Comment: A better solution would be to store the numeric value in a number column and have a separate column to store the currency.  When it comes to storing data strong typing is always safer.  As it stands right now, the users can put any old tat into your column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `regexp_replace` to keep only numeric characters and the decimal point, and `to_number` to convert the result to a number:

```
select *
from sales
order by to_number(regexp_replace(string_num_field, '[^0-9.]+', ''))
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d46e/2/0

Comment: Looks great in the sql fiddle, however it throws a large text of errors for me when trying to run with it.

Comment: Actually, it was my mis-understanding of the code you posted. It is now working properly!

Answer (score 1):

If all of your strings have the same format -- starting with a currency symbol, commas separator (if appropriate) and two decimal places -- then you can use the following:

```
order by length(saleamount) desc,
         saleamount desc
```

If you want the smallest value first, then:

```
order by length(saleamount) asc,
         saleamount asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an old-fashioned solution without regex:

```
select amt_usd
       , to_number(translate(amt_usd, '1234567890.,$', '1234567890.')) amt
from t23
order by 2
/
```

Working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fde16/4).

Of course, this will break if the users have put `£` or something else in the column.  The regex is safer from that perspective.